# Why is $\sin(\theta)$ not U-estimable in this example?

Tags: distributions, estimation

For completeness I give the definition of being U-estimable:

An estimator $\delta$ is called unbiased for $g(\theta)$ if $E_{\theta} \delta(X) = g(\theta) \ \forall \theta \in \Omega $.

If an unbiased estimator exists, g is called U-estimable.

[image]

Could I not try to taylor expand $sin(\theta)$ ? I am failing to see why this is so immediate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LHS is a polynomial in $\theta$ of degree no more than $n$. $\sin \theta$ is not a polynomial. Therefore the two functions cannot be equal.

Proof that $\sin \theta$ is not a polynomial even on $(0, 1)$: repeatedly differentiate it. If it were a polynomial, eventually you'd get the zero function. But you don't; you just alternate among $\{\pm \sin \theta, \pm \cos \theta\}$. ([h/t](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2lb98j/are_there_polynomial_equations_that_are_equal_to/cltiep2))

You can try Taylor-expanding $\sin \theta$ to get a degree $n$ approximation; you can get a very good approximation, as you can [for all continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). But it won't be equal at all points, just kind of close. The definition requires exact equality everywhere.

Comment: Oh ok so only asymptotically is $sinx$ a polynomial not for finite $n$. Correct?

Comment: The language is a little loose there, but yes, you can think of $\sin$ as an infinite-dimensional polynomial (as you can any continuous function).